# ¿Como puedo introducir una palabra y recorrer un bucle cuya salida sea las letras del abecedario no utilizadas en dicha palabra?

Tags: java

Tengo declarado una variable tipo `String` cuyo valor es introducido por teclado y dos variables de tipo `String` mas, que recogen los caracteres usados y no usados en dicha palabra.

Mi problema consiste en que no encuentro la manera de sacar el abecedario completo excluyendo las letras utilizadas. Este me sale **n** veces repetido por cada vez que recorre cada letra.

Es decir si la palabra introducida es **("hola")** su salida es una cadena que va desde la 'a' hasta la 'z' excluyendo la 'h' y así con el resto de las letras.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Dime una palabra");
    String palabra = sc.nextLine();
    String letrasNO = "";
    String letrasSI = "";

    for(int i=0; i<palabra.length(); i++) {

        for(char letra ='a'; letra<='z'; letra++) {

            if(palabra.charAt(i) != letra ) {

                letrasNO = letrasNO + letra;

            }else{

                letrasSI = letrasSI + letra;

            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(letrasNO);
    System.out.println(letrasSI);

    }

}
```

Comment: Quizás podrías utilizar una expresión regular, te proporciono un par de enlaces donde encontraras la mejor manera de utilizar las expresiones regulares, incluyo una pagina donde puedes crear las expresiones regulares y hacer un test de las mismas.
[En este enlace encontraras como realizar las expresiones regulares](https://regex101.com/r/5yEYI3/3)
[Como utilizar expresiones regulares](https://https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/javascript/capitulo-11.html)
[Aquí encontraras como extraer letras de cadenas utilizando expresiones regulares](https://diego.com.es/expresiones-regulares-en-php)
Saludos

Comment: Puedes convertir la "palabra" en un arreglo e iterar sobre este arreglo para saber si se contiene o no la letra en el abecedario @TALBARA

Answer (score 2):

Podría utilizar un Set para ir removiendo las letras que va encontrando.

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //creamos un Set con las letra del abecedario
            Set<Character> abecedario = new HashSet<Character>();
            for (char letra = 'a'; letra <= 'z'; letra++) {
                abecedario.add(letra);
            }

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Dime una palabra");
            String palabra = sc.nextLine();
            StringBuilder letrasNO= new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
                /*
                *Se van removiendo las letras que existen en la palabra 
                *para dejar en el Set solo con las que no se encontraron
                */
                if (abecedario.contains(palabra.charAt(i))) {
                    abecedario.remove(palabra.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            //Se concatenan las que letras que no se encontraron
            for (Character character : abecedario) {
                letrasNO.append(character);
            }

            System.out.println("No contiene:"+letrasNO.toString());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un array en base a las letras del abecedario y otro en base a las letras de la palabra para iterar y realizar la comparación:

```
    String abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";

    //Convierte a array la palabra introducida
    char[] letrasPalabra = palabra.toCharArray();
```

de esta forma si encuentras coincidencia, la eliminas de la variable que contiene el abecedario:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Dime una palabra");
    String palabra = sc.nextLine();
    String letrasNO = "";
    String letrasSI = "";


    String abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";

    //Convierte a array la palabra introducida
    char[] letrasPalabra = palabra.toCharArray();

        //itera sobre array que contiene las letras de la palabra introducida
        for (char letraPalabra : letrasPalabra) {

            for (int i = 0; i<=abecedario.length();i++) {
                //Busca si abecedario contiene la letra de la palabra
                if (abecedario.contains(String.valueOf(letraPalabra).toLowerCase())) { 
                    System.out.println("Encontro: " + String.valueOf(letraPalabra).toLowerCase());
                    //Elimina letra de abecedario.                        
                    abecedario = abecedario.replace(String.valueOf(letraPalabra).toLowerCase(), "");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Letras no usadas: " + abecedario);
```

Ejemplo de entrada:

```
Dime una palabra
¿Hola TALBARA como estas?
```

Salida:

```
Letras no usadas: dfgijknñpquvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Dime una palabra");
String palabra = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
String abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
```

He utilizado las mismas variables que tu, excepto por `abecedario`, variable de tipo `String` que contiene desde la **a** hasta la **z** . Adicional a eso he puesto que lo que se obtiene por el `Scanner` sea todo en minúsculas para comparar sin problemas con `toLowerCase()`.

---

Después de lo anterior, he creado un método `for` similar al tuyo.

1. Repasa la palabra completa, carácter por carácter.
2. Si es que la variable abecedario contiene el carácter `palabra.charAt(i)` se reemplaza por un espacio en blanco

```java
 //encuentra char y lo elimina
for(int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++){
   if(abecedario.contains(String.valueOf(palabra.charAt(i)))){
       abecedario = abecedario.replace(String.valueOf(palabra.charAt(i)), "");  
   }
}
System.out.println(abecedario);//imprimo el abecedario sin las letras que tiene la palabra
```

**SALIDA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]